# Interpolate Entitiypositions received from Server

Tags: networking, interpolation, fixed-timestep, timestep, extrapolation

I want to Inter, or perhaps, extrapolate the positions of gameentities on the client. Those positions are received from the Server. The vague updaterate of the server makes it difficult to implement.

The Game is a html5 mmo tbs(turnbased strategy) game. That means you have a huge map with lots of players with their bases and tanks and so on. Units move on a grid 
[image: Unit on the field]

**Here is how the Server works:**

- Node.js Server, so no true multithreading
- Authoritative Server (Physics are calculated here)
- Physics Loop 15ms / Update Loop 45ms
- Physics loop calculates new position every 200ms*
- Updates Client only when something changes (so no heartbeat or whatsoever)
- Update contains the path and the current position
- TCP is used to update Clients

(*roughly, because some units are faster, and if driving diagonally, the pythagoras theorem is used -> ~283ms)

This means that the server provides updates roughly every 200ms. But due to     phase shift of the physic and update loop, as well as lags the real update times are like these:

`3314, 239, 206, 177, 186, 2136, 218, 210, 204, 189, 221, 194`
Note the bigger numbers `3314, 2136` are caused when the unit did not receive an update for a longer time. As far as I understand, the aberration of the numbers are caused by the 45ms of the updateloop. So the worst-case would be 200 +/- 45 ms (No lag taken into account)

**What have I tried so far**

I am currently using Interpolation but the movement is very choppy. I guess it is because of the uncertain updatetimes and perhaps because the current position of the unit is overwritten which messes with my interpolation. I am calculating the interpolation for each unit respectively. The clientside renderloop takes place roughly every 50ms

Following Code is all on the client.

This is the Code when updates happen:

```
updatePosition : function(unit,x,y){
    unit.position.x = x;
    unit.position.y = y;
    unit.lastPosUpdate = Date.now();
}
```

This is the interpolation calculation:

```
interpolateSingle : function(unit){

    if (unit.lastAnimationTime){
        unit.drawingInterpolationFactor =
                (unit.lastAnimationTime-unit.lastPosUpdate)/(200) *(-1)
        if (unit.drawingInterpolationFactor>0){
            unit.drawingInterpolationFactor = 0;
        }
        if (unit.drawingInterpolationFactor<-1){
            unit.drawingInterpolationFactor = -1;
        }
    } else {
        unit.drawingInterpolationFactor = 0;
    }
    unit.lastAnimationTime = Date.now();

    if(unit.lastPosUpdate){
        //map.grid is 64 Pixels, unit.position is the worldposition in the grid
        //unit.sprite.position is the worldposition in pixels
        var dX = unit.position.x - (unit.sprite.position.x / map.grid);
        var dY = unit.position.y - (unit.sprite.position.y / map.grid) ;

        unit.sprite.position.x = unit.sprite.position.x - dX * map.grid * unit.drawingInterpolationFactor
        unit.sprite.position.y = unit.sprite.position.y - dY * map.grid * unit.drawingInterpolationFactor
    }
}
```

[image: choppy unit movement]

I guess my approach is pretty miserable. So what did I do wrong, what more
do I have to take into account? I do have information about the Path, tho, So I could theoreticaly extrapolate?